# regex.exec runs in a loop forever

Tags: javascript, regex, while-loop

So i have a text:

> > Ankenævnet har vedtaget at stadfæste huslejenævnets afgørelse. Dette medfører, at lejen er nedsat fra 207.437,60 kr. svarende til 1.152 kr.
> >     pr. m² til 180.000 kr. svarende til 1.000 kr. pr. m². (dissens)
> >     Lejenedsættelsen har virkning fra 1. januar 2011.
> >     Trappelejeforhøjelsen pr. 1. juli 2011 kan endvidere ikke godkendes.
> >     Lejen skal derfor fortsat være 180.000 kr. årligt fra denne dato.
> >     Depositum er tilsvarende nedsat til 45.000 kr. svarende til 3 måneders
> >     godkendt leje og forudbetalt leje til 30.000 kr. svarende til 2
> >     måneders godkendt leje.   Udlejer har pligt til at tilbagebetale for
> >     meget betalt leje, depositum og forudbetalt leje med renter efter
> >     renteloven fra betalingstidspunkterne.   Der henvises til lejelovens §
> >     113 a, jf. bilag. tilbagebetaling af for meget betalt leje, depositum,
> >     forudbetalt leje og renter senere end 1. august 2012 anses som en
> >     overtrædelse af disse bestemmelser.

And then the following piece of javascript code:

```
function getMatches(string, regex, index) {
    index || (index = 1); // default to the first capturing group
    var matches = [];
    var match;
    while (match = regex.exec(string)) {
        matches.push(match[index]);
    }
    return matches;
}


var myString = breadText;
var myRegEx = regStr;

var matches = getMatches(myString, myRegEx, 1);

console.log(matches);
```

**Note that the variable breadText is the above-shown text**

Running this will result in a forever loop ( the while loop) will run forever and keep adding the same result to the matches array.

I simply cannot understand why?

Can anyone see what ive done wrong?

Comment: What is the pattern? It must be matching an empty string.

Comment: Instead of that loop, just use `var matches = string.match(regex)`.

Comment: Add this line inside the `while` loop, `if (match.index === regex.lastIndex) regex.lastIndex++;`

Comment: Please add the relevant code you are using to the question (the regex must be included to fully understand your situation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of that loop, just use `var matches = string.match(regex)`.

If you construct your regex properly, there should be no need to loop over separate matches, especially not if you're just going to push the results into a array any way.

Comment: I am almost sure this will not work because the regex contains the global modifier (otherwise, there should be no `while`) and when a global modifier is used, `match()` does not remember the captured values. It is only good for extracting whole matches.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: `"1234".match(/\d/)` vs `"1234".match(/\d/g)`. `.match` does exactly what you need with the `g` flag.

Comment: It won't be so easy if you need to only get a capture group value. You will need to loop through the match objects.

Comment: Looping through a finite array is still less error-prone than a uncertain set of regex matches.

Comment: With your code, you [cannot extract just numbers from `"Num:12, Num:67"` with `/Num:(\d+)/g`](https://jsfiddle.net/b2zftgak/1/). You need [`RegExp#exec` and loop through the matches](https://jsfiddle.net/b2zftgak/2/).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Looks like my answer was accepted. In the end, it's what the OP needed.

Comment: Great, but the question does not even hint at the fact that this solution can work. If you expand your answer, I would be able to relieve the downvote.

Comment: Expand how? This answer is a nudge in the right direction. That's all it needed to be.